# C++ Singleton template class inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, singleton, friend

I have an abstract Singleton class. My goal is that any subclasses just have to implement the init() function AND NOTHING ELSE. Here is what I did:

```
template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
    public: 

        Singleton()
        {
            init();
        }

        static T& instance()
        {
            static T instance;
            return instance;
        }

    protected:
        virtual void init() = 0;   
};

class SubSingleton : public Singleton<SubSingleton>
{
    protected: 
        void init()
        {
            cout << "Init SubSingleton" << endl;
        }
};
```

This won't compile, since init() is protected and can't be called from a public static function. There are 2 solutions to this problem. First we can make the init() function public, but I don't want to expose this function publicly. So this only leaves the second solution, change the subclass as follows:

```
class SubSingleton : public Singleton<SubSingleton>
{
    friend class Singleton<SubSingleton>;

    protected:

        void init()
        {
            cout << "Init SubSingleton" << endl;
        }
};
```

This works perfectly, but I don't want the friend statement, since other programmers might extend my code and might not know that this should be added.

Is there any other way of implementing this without the friend statement? Maybe anything from Andrei Alexandrescu?

**EDIT: The init function is now called in the constructor instead of the instance() function.**

**EDIT2: For technical reasons and compatibility I need an init() function and can't just do the initialization in the constructor.**

**The solution for casting works, but if I call init() from the constructor the casting doesn't work anymore. Any suggestions?**

Comment: Calling `instance()` twice will cause `init()` be called twice: is this normal?

Comment: What is your with `template<class> Singleton;`? It doesn't seem to require derived classes to actually be singletons so wouldn't it be simpler to just let derived classes perform their initialization in their constructors as they would normally? (In fact, even if you want to required derived classes to be singletons I still don't see a reason for an "init" function that is always called immediately after a constructor.)

Comment: first: you do not create the instance right now, second: a bool isInit will help, but what you expect here is probably a Create and not an Init. seems a little mixed up at the moment.

Comment: After your "edit2": you shouldn't call init() from base constructor, because when a constructor of base is being called, the derived object (i.e. its members) doesn't exist yet. So even if you'd call derived::init() statically you couldn't do there anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that you do not use the virtual function as you intend to use. i,e there no polymorphism in action now. Why? because you call init() on the direct derived object. The use of init() function being virtual is when you invoke init() either on the base-class reference or on base class pointer as given below. Then the invocation happens from the base-class scope and since instance() method is a base class method, calling a protected method from that is perfectly fine.

```
    static T& instance()
    {
        static T myInstance;
        Singleton<T>& t = myInstance;  // Just define a dummy reference here.
        t.init();
        return myInstance;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You do not need this init() stuff at all. It only makes problems here.

```
template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
    public: 
        static T& instance()
        {
            static T instance;
            return instance;
        }
};

class SubSingleton : public Singleton<SubSingleton>
{
    public: 
        SubSingleton()
        {
            cout << "Init SubSingleton" << endl;
        }
};
```

In this way you not only remove unnecessary stuff - but you also prevent from calling init() every time someone calls instanse()...

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you mix 2 types of polimorphysms:

1) If you want to call `SubSingleton::init()` "statically", i.e. using CRTP, you don't need to define it in the base class -- but then you really have to make it accessible for the base class.

2) But if you define init() as virtual, you use dynamic polimorphism, and don't need to make `init()` public:

```
static T& instance() 
{ 
  static T instance; 
  static_cast<Singleton<T> &>(instance).init(); 
  return instance; 
}
```

Comment: +1 good point, but you used the name `instance` both for the function template and a variable within its body. this won't compile.

Comment: @Walter could you reference the Standard paragrhaph that forbids this? As far as I remember it's allowed.

Comment: maybe it is allowed, but it really wont compile due to ambigious names

Comment: @Mare Infinitus , there's no ambiguity here, and it compiles well (tested with MSVC10).

Comment: @Mare: is allowed and compiles with gcc